# What is the section ID (name) for "Menus" in the Customizer?

Tags: theme-customizer, settings-api

I browsed many articles to know the section Name of the "Menu" in the theme customizer. Here are the few resources that proclaim and identifies that the default section name is "nav" →

1. https://wptheming.com/2012/06/add-options-to-theme-customizer-default-sections/
2. http://natko.com/changing-default-wordpress-theme-customization-api-sections/

Currently, there are 5 fields that are resting in the →

```
title_tagline - Site Title & Tagline
```

but as soon as I change their section name to :

```
'section'  => 'nav',
```

The fields do not appear inside the menu section. whats the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Customizer > Menus* is a *panel* named `nav_menus`.

*Customizer > Menus > Menu Locations* is a section inside the `nav_menus` panel called `menu_locations`.

Each menu is added a little differently, but I believe they are sections inside the `nav_menus` panel whose ID is `nav_menu[menu_id]'` where `menu_id` is the `term_id` of the menu.

*Customizer > Menus > Add a Menu* is a section inside the `nav_menus` panel called `add_menu`, with a priority of `999`.

Browsing core code is the best way to find this stuff out. All this stuff is in `/wp-includes/class-wp-customize-nav-menus.php`

Both those articles pre-date Customizer menus by 3 & 2 years, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Just having a very quick look, it seems that the section is actually `nav_menus` and not `nav`.

Note that those articles are 4+ years old so cannot necessarily be relied on as current.