# WordPress Customizer: Why widgets and nav_menus are components, not panel or section?

Tags: theme-customizer

As mentioned in my question my wigets and nav_menus are components, why not panels? What is the difference between a component and panel/section(I understand both are containers for controls)

Is it because both don't have controls and has different functionality from normal form controls?

I understand that I can create custom control, Can I also create custom component?

Comment: See my answer [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/281452/39152) for some info on how menus are set up inside the customiser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A component in the Customizer is just a way for core to allow for plugins to determine whether or not the functionality is loaded. Functionality in the Customizer involves much more than just adding a panel. It also involves logic for previewing, enqueuing scripts, and so on. So there are components for widgets and nav menus in order to provide a way for a plugin to turn off all of a component's functionality, without having to know all of the hooks that a component integrates with. Read more on [#33552](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/33552) for why the filter was introduced. Both widgets and nav menus have panels, but they also have classes (`WP_Customize_Widgets` and `WP_Customize_Nav_Menus` respectively) which manage the registration of the panels and all of the other things the functionalities need. You can certainly create your own custom classes to organize your Customizer code in the same way. The [Customize Posts](https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts) plugin does this by hooking into the same filter to give plugins the opportunity to turn the functionality of if needed: https://github.com/xwp/wp-customize-posts/blob/9550566/php/class-customize-posts-plugin.php#L70-L71

Comment: Thank you for explanation. After seeing source code of the mentioned classes, it comes clear why components are needed.